# How to find probabilities using normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Pumpkins from a large crop are found to have a mean weight of 4.1kg with a standard deviation of 0.45kg. Calculate the probability that a pumpkin weighs between 3.5 and 4.5 kg.

I worked out that the z value is -2.444 (rounded to 3dp). The correct probability should be 0.4927, but I get 0.4928 from the table. How do I get the correct answer?[image]

Comment: If you rounded the z value to 3 decimal places, and your answer is accurate to 3 decimal places, then the difference is probably due to rounding. But if you show your work, someone may be able to verify that it’s correct, or point out any errors.

Comment: I really don’t think 0.4927 can be the right answer, because the probability of the weight being within one standard deviation of the mean (between 3.65kg and 4.55kg) is 0.6827

Answer (score 1):

I don’t get that at all. I get two z scores, one for each side:

$z = (4.5 - 4.1)/0.45 = 0.8888$ with probability 0.3131

$z = (3.5 - 4.1)/0.45 = -1.3333$ with probability (for $z=1.3333$) 0.4087

For a total probability of 0.7218

Also, I checked my answer using a computer:

```
> pnorm(4.5, mean = 4.1, sd = 0.45) - pnorm(3.5, mean = 4.1, sd = 0.45)
[1] 0.7217574
```